# Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS not recognized

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I cannot get CMake (3.16.4) and boost to work together like they should.

My system has boost installed (v1.72), and I compiled another version like so:

```
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.71.0/source/boost_1_71_0.tar.gz
tar -xf boost_1_71_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_71_0 && ./bootstrap.sh && ./b2 --prefix=../external/boost_1_71_0 --with-timer install
```

I have a simple test program using a boost timer:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
    std::cout << "Hello Timer" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And that's the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.4)

Project(CmakeBoostText)

set(Boost_DEBUG 1)
set(Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT ../external/boost_1_71_0)
find_package(Boost 1.71 REQUIRED COMPONENTS timer)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main Boost::timer)
```

Then I try to compile my test binary:

```
rm -rf build/* && cmake -S . -B build && cmake --build build
```

In the output, there you can clearly see that he is using the system variant of boost:

```
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1468 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = "ON"
-- [ /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1537 ] BOOST_ROOT = "../external/boost_1_71_0"
[...]
Found Boost: /usr/lib64/cmake/Boost-1.72.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.72.0", minimum required is "1.71") found components: timer
```

Using ldd I can also verify the binary is linked to the system library of boost.

This is quite odd. According to the documentation in cmake/find_package, `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` should handle this.

If I then change the find_package to include 'EXACT' it suddenly works (it finds and uses the correct version. But I consider this to be a big hack.

```
find_package(Boost 1.71 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS timer)
```

Why is that not working without `EXACT`? Clarifications welcome.

Note: I don't want to use anything involving `include_directories()`. So these workarounds are out of scope.

Comment: It is difficult to say what is going on, without more information. In general, [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) has two modes, Module and Config. I think the variable `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` only applies to Module mode. So if Module mode fails for some reason, it falls back to Config mode and searches your system paths as well. And when you specify a version, this is a *minimum* version, so 1.71 or 1.72 are valid options. If you want a *specific* version, use `EXACT`.

Comment: Sure, but if I say "don't use the system path" and the rest is valid, it still uses the system path. Why this should depend on `EXACT` is not clear to me at all.

Comment: As @squareskittles commented, `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` actually doesn't affect on `CONFIG` mode searching performed [inside FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L444) script. I don't know whether this is intended or not, but this is how it currently works. You may disable searching with `CONFIG` mode by setting `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` variable to ON. Such way, `Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS` will be fully preserved.

Comment: Why your case works with `EXACT` option: Every parameters you pass to original `find_package(Boost)` is transferred (indirectly) to the inner `CONFIG` mode searching. If searching in `CONFIG` mode fails (e.g. because of incompatible version), then searching fallbacks to "usual" Find script searching with `find_path` and `find_library`.